# Is Ledoit-Wolf Shrinkage with a Constant Correlation Prior Reasonable for a Stock/Bond Mix?

Tags: portfolio-optimization, covariance, diversification, covariance-estimation

I've been looking into [Ledoit-Wolf](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=433840) shrinkage but I've found the papers concentrate on large numbers of assets that tend to all be highly correlated.  Often a universe of large cap stocks.

I'm concerned that portfolio with a mix of stocks and bonds ETFs the bonds may in steady state have a near zero correlation with the stocks and the constant correlation matrix would be a poor prior.

I note that [Betterment](https://www.betterment.com/resources/research/betterment-portfolio-strategy/#citations) uses shrinkage in their stock/bond asset allocation but they don't talk about their prior.  Does there exist well reasoned work exploring good priors for diverse portfolios?